# symfony catch block doesnt stop error propagation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have these entities

```
    /**
 * nmarea
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"area"}, message="error.nmArea.area.unique")
 * @ORM\Table(name="master.nmarea")
 * @Tenant
 */
class nmArea
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 **/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="error.nmArea.area.blank")
 * @ORM\Column(name="area", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 **/
private $area;
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="eliminado", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 **/
private $eliminado;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="nmEmpresa")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_empresa", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $empresa;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="nmUsuario")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_representante", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="error.nmArea.representante.blank")
 */
private $representante;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmpresa()
{
    return $this->empresa;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $empresa
 */
public function setEmpresa($empresa)
{
    $this->empresa = $empresa;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getRepresentante()
{
    return $this->representante;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $representante
 */
public function setRepresentante($representante)
{
    $this->representante = $representante;
}


/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getArea()
{
    return $this->area;
}

/**
 * @param string $area
 */
public function setArea($area)
{
    $this->area = $area;
}

/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getEliminado()
{
    return $this->eliminado;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $eliminado
 */
public function setEliminado($eliminado)
{
    $this->eliminado = $eliminado;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->area;
}



}
```

and

```
    /**
 * nmentidad_area
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="master.nmentidad_area")
 * @Tenant
 */

class nmEntidadArea
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_entidad_area", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 **/
private $id;


/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="eliminado", type="boolean")
 **/
private $eliminado;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="nmEmpresa")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_empresa", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $empresa;



/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="nmEntidad", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_entidad", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $entidad;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="nmArea")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_area", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $area;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getArea()
{
    return $this->area;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $area
 */
public function setArea($area)
{
    $this->area = $area;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEntidad()
{
    return $this->entidad;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $entidad
 */
public function setEntidad($entidad)
{
    $this->entidad = $entidad;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmpresa()
{
    return $this->empresa;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $empresa
 */
public function setEmpresa($empresa)
{
    $this->empresa = $empresa;
}


/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getEliminado()
{
    return $this->eliminado;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $eliminado
 */
public function setEliminado($eliminado)
{
    $this->eliminado = $eliminado;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->entidad->getNombre() . $this->area->getArea();
}


}
```

When I want to delete an nmArea instance I use this service

```
namespace AplicacionBaseBundle\DependencyInjection\Helpers;

use AplicacionBaseBundle\Entity\nmEntidad;
use AplicacionBaseBundle\Entity\nmEntidadArea;
use AplicacionBaseBundle\Entity\nmArea;
use Doctrine\DBAL\ConnectionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConstraintViolationException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class SpamEntityHelper implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
use ContainerAwareTrait;

//... other code



public function deleteEntitySpam($repository, $id, $trueDelete = false, $hasRelations = false)
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    $em->getConnection()->setTransactionIsolation(Connection::TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
    try {
        $spamManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository($repository);
        $spam = $spamManager->find($id);
        if ($trueDelete == false) {
            $spam->setEliminado(true);
            if (!$hasRelations) {
                $cloned = clone $spam;
                $em->remove($spam);
                $em->flush();
                $em->persist($cloned);
                $em->flush();
            }
        } else {

            $em->remove($spam);
            $em->flush();
        }
        $em->getConnection()->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (DBALException $e) {
        $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
        $em->clear();
        $this->container->get('doctrine')->resetEntityManager();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thing is when I try to delete a nmArea object without removing it from nmEntidadArea first, Doctrine throws a ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException right in the commit line of the  above service, and that is good: you cant delete if stills referenced, of course. What I cant figure out is why that error cant be catched with the try/catch block, nor like DBALException nor ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException: it doesnt matter how many catch I put, there is no way to deal with it.
I was thinking on subscribing to kernel.exception, but then I break the flow of the method and `$em->getConnection()->rollBack();` throws that **there is no active transaction**

The full trace of error is this

> exception […]
>   0   PDOException
>   message SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: update o delete en «nmarea» viola la llave foránea «const_fk_nmentidadarea_representante» en la tabla «nmentidad_area» DETAIL: La llave (id)=(17) todavía es referida desde la tabla «nmentidad_area».
>   class   PDOException
>   trace   […]
>   0   {…}
>   namespace
>   short_class 
>   class
>   type
>   function
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php
>   line    1289
>   args    []
>   1   PDO
>   namespace
>   short_class PDO
>   class   PDO
>   type    ->
>   function    commit
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php
>   line    1289
>   args    []
>   2   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
>   namespace   Doctrine\DBAL
>   short_class Connection
>   class   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
>   type    ->
>   function    commit
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\src\AplicacionBaseBundle\DependencyInjection\Helpers\SpamEntityHelper.php
>   line    103
>   args    []
>   3   AplicacionBaseBundle\DependencyInjection\Helpers\SpamEntityHelper
>   namespace   AplicacionBaseBundle\DependencyInjection\Helpers
>   short_class SpamEntityHelper
>   class   AplicacionBaseBundle\DependencyInjection\Helpers\SpamEntityHelper
>   type    ->
>   function    deleteEntitySpam
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\src\AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\NomenclatorsController.php
>   line    45
>   args    […]
>   4   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\NomenclatorsController
>   namespace   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller
>   short_class NomenclatorsController
>   class   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\NomenclatorsController
>   type    ->
>   function    deleteENTITYAction
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\src\AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\NomenclatorsController.php
>   line    82
>   args    […]
>   5   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\NomenclatorsController
>   namespace   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller
>   short_class NomenclatorsController
>   class   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\NomenclatorsController
>   type    ->
>   function    performDeleteAction
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\src\AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\AreaController.php
>   line    58
>   args    […]
>   6   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\AreaController
>   namespace   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller
>   short_class AreaController
>   class   AplicacionBaseBundle\Controller\AreaController
>   type    ->
>   function    deleteAreaAction
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php
>   line    151
>   args    […]
>   7   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel
>   namespace   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel
>   short_class HttpKernel
>   class   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel
>   type    ->
>   function    handleRaw
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php
>   line    68
>   args    […]
>   8   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel
>   namespace   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel
>   short_class HttpKernel
>   class   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel
>   type    ->
>   function    handle
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php
>   line    169
>   args    […]
>   9   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel
>   namespace   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel
>   short_class Kernel
>   class   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel
>   type    ->
>   function    handle
>   file    D:\xmp\htdocs\protosoft\web\app_dev.php
>   line    29

**UPDATE 1**

After trying( again) the solutions provided in the answers without result I began to believe that it was not a properly said 'doctrine or symfony problem'. So i ran the delete query on my pgadmin(I m using postgresql) and the query result was exactly the same that in my app, literally the same:

> update o delete en «nmarea» viola la llave foránea «const_fk_nmentidadarea_representante» en la tabla «nmentidad_area»
>   DETAIL:  La llave (id)=(17) todavía es referida desde la tabla «nmentidad_area».

So, what I think is that when I try to delete Symfony and/or Doctrine look for errors and everything is Ok, but then the database returns the error, and for some reason the server does not handle that error and ends up being a fatal error, which is handled as a kernel error. But why?

Comment: Doesn't the stack trace say PDOException?

Answer (score 0):

You’re getting a `PDOException`, while you’re catch is limited to `DBALException` – which is not an instance of `PDOException`! So, obviously, the exception doesn’t get caught.

If you want to catch both types of exceptions, you can use the newly introduced catch pipe operator:

```
try 
{
    // …
}
catch (PDOException | DBALException $e)
{
    // …
}
```

This works in PHP 7.1 and higher. If your code needs to run on servers with PHP < 7.1, you could listen for just any exception and then determine the type of exception within the `catch` block:

```
try 
{
    // …
} 
catch (Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof PDOException || $e instanceof DBALException)
    {
        // …
    }
    else 
    {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Or you could use multiple catch blocks:

```
try 
{
    // …
} 
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    // …
}
catch (DBALException $e)
{
    // …
}
```

Either way, remember to import namespaces properly, otherwise exceptions will not be caught.

Comment: Sorry the late. It doesn't matter if PDO or DBALException, just cant be catched. Please read my update.